# Different order of objects while looping individually and printing all at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a response object, which has a key tags whose value is a json. I am trying to sort the json based on a key, then iterating through the list and pushing the objects to a react list. I see that when I print individually, they are coming as expected, but when I print as a whole, they are not in the same order.

```
sortTags: function (response) {
    tagss = []
    response.tags.sort((a, b) => a.disp_id - b.disp_id).map(function(tag) {
        console.log(tag)
        tagss.push(tag)
    });
    console.log(tagss)
    return tagss;
}
```

I see that when I do `console.log(tag)`, it is printing in the order as expected. But `console.log(tagss)` is printing in a different order.

The question maybe very naive. Please do help. Thank you, in advance.

Comment: Could you post a codesandbox or a stackblitz link?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? `tagss` being somehow clone of sorted tags?

Comment: @Apostolos Yes sir. I am expecting tagss to be sorted based on the disp_id key. I am also wondering, how an array or list's order is changed automatically. Thank you

Comment: @a2441918 sir/madam, my code belongs to react 0.10 version. I am not familiar with newer versions and codesandbox and stackblitz are throwing exceptions for my code.

Comment: I made a sandbox example of your code and it works as expected : https://playcode.io/641862/

Comment: @ÇağataySel this is not working. log is showing not ordered array. also i don't understand the use of `map` function here. it doesnt do anything. it is useless in this senario.

Comment: @Apostolos it does in my browser. I have added console logs for individual elements and it prints the array in the same order as console.log in map function

Comment: Try `console.log(tagss.join(' '))` - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4057440/1048572

Comment: @ÇağataySel now it's working ok. but still i dont understand how to reproduce the senario that Basant is saying.

Comment: @BasantkumarBhala You don't need map to do this. `sort` will return a newly created sorted array. You just have to do `const tagss = response.tags.sort((a, b) => a.disp_id - b.disp_id);`.

Comment: Thank you every one for helping me out. 
@Apostolos sir, I don't know why you deleted your answer but [].concat actually worked for me. I couldn't mark your answer immediately and now, I couldn't find yours. Regarding the scenario, is it possible that I am facing it because my react version is too old?

Comment: @ÇağataySel I am surprised how we have the same code but the output is different for me. I don't know if it boils down to the factor that my react version is very old. I am thankful for your help.

Comment: @BasantkumarBhala I undeleted my answer. now it is visible again. this is pure js. it doesnt have to do - i guess - with how old the react version is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `map` to do this. `sort` will return a <del>newly created</del> sorted array. You just have to clone the `tags` array using the spread operator `...` and then return the sort result `return response.tags.sort((a, b) => a.disp_id - b.disp_id)`.

#### Run snippet to see it in action

```js
const resp = {
  tags: [{
    name: "Nikos",
    disp_id: 45,
  }, {
    name: "Giorgos",
    disp_id: 25,
  }, {
    name: "Adreas",
    disp_id: 21,
  }, {
    name: "Maria",
    disp_id: 67,
  }, {
    name: "Panos",
    disp_id: 19,
  }]
};

const Sorter = {
  sortTags: function(response) {
    return [...response.tags].sort((a, b) => a.disp_id - b.disp_id);
  }
}

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(
  Sorter.sortTags(resp)
, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help. Since sort returns a newly sorted array, I guess I wont need to use 'tagss' in my code. Thanks a lot

Comment: @BasantkumarBhala what I wrote was wrong. `sort` won't create a new array. You'll have to copy it using spread operator `[...array]` before you use sort. Check my updated answer which does that.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `sort` method and then if you want to clone the array, you could use `concat`.

```
response.tags.sort((a, b) => a.disp_id - b.disp_id)
tagss = [].concat(tags)
```

Comment: Initially I tried assigning the result of sort again to response.tags and then I observed that it did not retain the order after assignment. Hence I thought of using a new array and copying into it but with no luck. Both of your answers provided me with some insight of js. Thank you so much.